# Webpack is not bundling a dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, axios

I have a Typescript library which uses Axios as following:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export class Connector { readonly axios = axios.create(); ... }
```

After publishing, I import the library in a new React project created with `create-react-app --template=typescript`. When I run the project in the browser and instantiate a new connector such as:

```
import { Connector } from 'mylib';
const connector = new Connector();
```

I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined` at the `axios.create()` call. Inspecting in the browser, it seems webpack is not bundling anything related to Axios (which is a dependency from `mylib`).

Now, If I **do** import Axios directly in the `App.tsx` file and call `axios.create()`, this last call works (but the call done inside the `mylib` library still does not work).

Basically the `axios` object is `undefined` inside `mylib`, and it seems webpack is producing an import for `node_modules/axios/dist/browser/axios.cjs`, which does not exist in the bundle for some reason.

What is happening here?

Using webpack 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Axios 1.1.3+, which is still broken: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5154

Downgrade to 1.1.2 and stuff works.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. It saved me Friday :-)